# Why does a homogeneous first-order linear PDE have $n-1$ functionally independent solutions?

Tags: linear-pde

Why does a homogeneous first-order linear PDE$$\sum_{i=0}^n\xi_i(\mathbf{x})\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}=0,$$where $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, …, x_n)$, have $n-1$ [functionally independent](https://mathoverflow.net/q/290507/69318) solutions for $u(\mathbf{x})$?

Comment: Your equation doesn't necessarily have even two functionally independent solutions, as its flow lines might form a foliation with a dense leaf, even on the open set where not all of the $\xi_i(x)$ vanish. You might try Arnold's book Ordinary Differential Equations to learn more about vector fields.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2601299/what-does-it-mean-for-functions-to-be-functionally-independent   and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2601309/why-does-a-homogeneous-first-order-linear-pde-have-n-1-functionally-independen

Comment: @BenMcKay  apart from  existence of dense leaves, existence of a limit cycle (say in  a  foliation of  torus)  is another obstruction for rxistence of a non constant    first  integral.